# Weighted Covariance

Tags: covariance

So X and Y are my random variables and they are vectors representing observations of actual production over predicted production ratios of two different factories. I want to weigh every observation by the number of staff in each factory, corresponding to the observation. (each observation is a monthly entry). I want to find the weighted covariance of the production ratios, weighted by the staff numbers in each factory.

Is there a formula to compute the weighted covariance?

Comment: I commented on your previous post, which you deleted. Could explain _I want to weigh every observation by the number of staff in each factory, corresponding to the observation._ How do you achieve it? Furthermore, you are dealing with a sample so you may be interested in the sample covariance and not the population covariance.

Comment: it is not clear what you wish to achieve by this weighting. Do you wish to take into account the fact that meeting the production expectations is also affected by employee count, and as such you wish to *adjust* the covariance for contributions from the employee count ?

Comment: @noVariation yes that is my thought process. I am expecting that the overall prediction ratios will have an effect due to the number of staff so I want to weigh each observation by the number of staff that are taken into account for that observation.